# TensorFlow: Multiple forward pass in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to do forward pass in Tensorflow multiple time, and backward pass one. Is that possible ?

For example:
Five time forward pass, if I have satisfied some condition to do backward.
Pseudo code:

```
for i in range(5):
    Forward Pass
    if i % 5 == 0:
       Backward pass
```

I tried to do that in this way:

```
batch_t = np.array(...)
batch_l = np.array(...)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, EVENT_SIZE))

# Hidden layer 1
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([FEATURE_NO, HIDDEN_1]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([HIDDEN_1]))
z1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, W1), b1)
a1 = tf.nn.relu(z1)

last = sess.run(a1, feed_dict={ x: batch_t }) 

if SOME CONDITION:

     target = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
     forward = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

     probs = classifier(logits=forward, labels=target)
     loss = tf.reduce_mean(probs)

     train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

     sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={ forward: last, target: batch_l})
```

But, I have problem, graph is cut at first line, I can't to connect variables from "model" and from part with classifier and optimizer.

I get error:

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables ["<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(10000, 10) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'Variable_1:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'Variable_2:0' shape=(10, 15) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'Variable_3:0' shape=(15,) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'Variable_4:0' shape=(15, 20) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'Variable_5:0' shape=(20,) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'Variable_6:0' shape=(20, 15) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'Variable_7:0' shape=(15,) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'Variable_8:0' shape=(15, 10) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'Variable_9:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32_ref>"] and loss Tensor("Mean:0", shape=(), dtype=float32).
```

If someone has solution for first or second kind of problem, I would be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the forward pass? In your current code there is no trainable variable (placeholders are not trainable), as the error message suggests.

Comment: I changed code, I hope now is much more clear. I have first part of graph evaluated and return value is "last", how to merge with second part of graph ? Because, I need to do forward pass few times, but back-prop only when "SOME CONDITION" is satisfied. Or you have another solution for multiple forward pass  and one backward pass.

Comment: I might see you problem. You should not define `forward` as a placeholder, but use `a1` instead of `forward` in `classifier(logits=a1, labels=target)`. You want to feed `x` in the `feed_dict`, not `forward`. Any placeholder is not trainable.